# import and export csv file in powershell

Tags: powershell

i have a csv file "emp.csv" with following information.

```
empid   status
1   t
2   a
3   t
4   t
5   a
```

I need empid and status of employees having status="t" and the output should be in "res.csv" file

Answer (score 5):

For this, you'll first want to import the existing data with `Import-Csv` - but since your file is technically a TSV (tab-separated instead of comma-separated), make sure you specify this with `` -Delimiter "`t" ``:

```
$employeeStatusData = Import-Csv .\path\to\emp.csv -Delimiter "`t"
```

`Import-Csv` will parse the input file and store the resulting objects in `$employeeStatusData`. To filter these object based on the value of the `status` property/column, use `Where-Object`:

```
$filteredEmployeeData = $employeeStatusData |Where-Object status -eq 't'
```

Now that you have the relevant rows selected, you can export the data again with `Export-Csv`:

```
$filteredEmployeeData |Export-Csv .\path\to\res.csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the tab delimiter! Thanks for this :)